# How to return Json from WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, json

I have the piece of code below of a template Ajax enabled WCF service. What can i do to make it return JSon instead of XML? 
thanks.

```
using System; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "WCFServiceEight")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CostService
{
    // Add [WebGet] attribute to use HTTP GET
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public double CostOfSandwiches(int quantity)
    {
        return 1.25 * quantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Comment: thanks.

Yes i tried but i still get error from the JQuery code. here is the code i am using to call the service:
 var parameters = 7

        $.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost:53153/TestWebServiceEightSite/CostService.svc",
       data: parameters,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result) {
       $("InputHTML").val(result);
       },
       error: function(e) {  
           alert(e);
       }
});

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the POST verb as in `$.ajax({ type: "POST", ...)` you will need to markup your method with `[WebInvoke(Method="POST"]`.

Since you marked it up with `[WebGet]` (which is equivalent to `[WebInvoke(Method="GET")]`) you should call the service using the GET verb, e.g.:

`$.ajax({ type: "GET", ...)` or use `$.get(url, data, ...)` (see [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more info).

And you'll need to set the ResponseFormat to Json, as `tomasr` already pointed out.