# Returning JSON from wcf in VS2010

Tags: wcf

I had created an asp.net mvc application and also added wcf application project in my asp .net         project. Now i want to create method in webservie to return json which will be consumed by my iPhone application.

Answer (score 0):

this would help you :

[JSON-Enabled WCF Services in ASP.NET 3.5](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx)

[How to return Json from WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830459/how-to-return-json-from-wcf-service)